# how to search and filter listview with searchManager

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm using String[] {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3"} as the arrayadapter which will show in my ListView, but the problem now is I cant filter for the search purpose. majority online tutorial are filtered and get from database, but for my case, I do not touch database at all, all of it just hard coded. Sorry for my English and help please :)

code as below:
MainActivity.java :

```
 String[] values = new String[] { "item 1", "item 2", "item 3" } ;
 ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, values);
 setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Adapter.java code as below

```
public class BuildingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 private final Context context;
 private final String[] buildingname;

  public BuildingAdapter(Context context, String[] buildingname) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_buidling_item, buildingname);
    this.context = context;
    this.buildingname = buildingname;
}
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_buidling_item, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buildingname);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buildingicon);
    TextView hints = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buildinghints);
    textView.setText(buildingname[position]);
    // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
    String s = buildingname[position];
  return rowView;
}




//that's all I did, hopefully someone can answer please...
```

Comment: If i understated correctly, you have 2 Array,  Array1 and Array2, You want to get the list  Array1  - Array2 ?

Comment: @RohitJain no sir, I have just one Array which is "buildingname".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Arrary Adapter for ListView**

```
// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Listview Data
    String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                            "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                            "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);       

}
```

**Enabling Search Functionality**

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
    }
});
```

**Finally add the following property in your AndroidManifest.xml file to hide the keyboard on loading Activity.**

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

[refference](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/)

Comment: thanks sir :) this really solve my problem , but I got another problem now, sorry for disturb again..
the item are display well in listview, but I need to display a different photo for different item in the listview. how should I do it? my photo are now all in Raw folder inside the Resource
sorry for my bad english

Comment: go with custom list adapter..for refference..go through thisk link   http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

Answer (score 0):

create two fields in your activity

```
String[] values;
ArrayList<String> filteredValues;
```

now assign the values to adapter like:

```
    values = new String[]{"item 1", "item 2", "item 3"};
    filteredValues = new ArrayList<>(values.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        filteredValues.add(values[i]);
    }
    ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

now define the filter method which you call to filter:

```
  private void filter(String s) {
    filteredValues.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s) || values[i].contains(s)) {
            filteredValues.add(values[i]);
        }
    }
    //notifyDatasetChange of adapter here;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

for those who have a same problem with me, I found the best example here :)
Take a look...
[listview getfilter for multiple string array (customized String[] or drawable images)](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/)

hope it help :)